# Shiny app is stalled when executing a big calculation

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

I'm new to shiny , couldn't get my answer anywhere tho.
I have a heavy code aggregating tables in R. I wanted to move it to the Web app and I chose Shiny as my original code is written in R so I thought it saves me lots of time.

When I run the code by

```
ObserveEvent(actionbutton$do,{mybigcalculation(input_tables)})
```

my code is running but at the time of executing my code, it's not possible to do other stuff like exploring tables in the other tabs.The rendering part works but he web app functionalities is completely frozen at the time the process is running.

Any help would be highly appreciated ? if this doesn't work I have to move to typical web app development by having backend ( e.g plumber ) and frontend (e.g React) in separate servers.

Thank you

Comment: If you want async app then have a look at this article https://blog.rstudio.com/2018/06/26/shiny-1-1-0/

Comment: Thank you @PorkChop . It just took the process to the background (So I can't see it in the console) but still the web app is stalled. That's how I used it this time.

  **Output <- reactive({ 
    
    future(mybigcalculation(input_tables))
    })
  
  observeEvent(input$actionbutton,{
    
    Output()
  })**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long investigation, I think I found the answer. I'm writing it down here as you might face this issue quite often developing your web app by Shiny. Always there are some big processes you wanna do and wanna make sure your async works great.
There are libraries (future &  promises packages) that Cheng explains them [here](https://blog.rstudio.com/2018/06/26/shiny-1-1-0/). it says, they can take the calculations in the background and make them come back with the result while the shiny app is doing its normal job. It didn't work for me and I still had my web app stalled. But what I saw, they did increase mybigcalculation speed dramatically. Also it took it to the background makes it invisible in the console.

I found my answer in a package called [Shiny.worker library](https://github.com/Appsilon/shiny.worker).
Now my app is working fine while my expensive code is running in the background. I made my ideal execution(fast and async) by wrapping **future** package inside of a **shiny worker** library.
So it looks something like this:

```
load.lib <- c("promises","future","shiny.worker")

install.lib <- load.lib[!load.lib %in% installed.packages()]
for(lib in install.lib) install.packages(lib,dependencies=TRUE)
sapply(load.lib,library,character=TRUE)

plan(multisession)
```

initiate the worker by:

```
worker <- shiny.worker::initialize_worker()
```

then:

```
wrapper <- function(args) {
  future::future(my_heavy_calculations(args$r))
}


reactive_arguments <- reactive({ 
  input$start
  list(r = rnorm(1))
})


resultPromise <- worker$run_job("job1", wrapper, args_reactive = reactive_arguments)

resultPromise()$result # contains the result of the calculations

resultPromise()$resolved # contains flag that informs whether the job has finished or not
```

I'm looking forward for any idea and suggestions that can makes the answer better.